# developer demand -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

> Java is, arguably, the most popular programming language in the world, used by millions of developers on almost every kind of computer imaginable. In the past decade, Java has surpassed languages such as C++ and Visual Basic in terms of **developer demand** and has become the de facto language for certain kinds of development—especially for web-based services.

How do you understand that phrase exactly?

Comment: I can think of two possibilities: the demand developers in general have vs. the demand for developers who are skillful in a specific language. Though I lean toward the latter, either reading works fine for me.

Comment: I go with the latter, since the former would be a reflection of the latter in any case. Eventually, of course, after the hype has died down.

Comment: As a developer, I've found there is little chance a developer can "demand" a language, but the expression **developer demand** means a **demand for developers skilled in the language**, as mentioned above. This phrase is an example of dubious "business speak"; see http://www.atrixnet.com/bs-generator.html for more jargon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it comes from "Supply and Demand", which is a term in economics.

Supply is the number of people selling a product, and Demand is the number of people who want it. *Developer* demand, in this case, is the number of developers who want to use Java more than visual Basic and C++.